# New to httpwebrequest in C# and expertise using webbrowsercontrol in VB.net Basic help needed to scrape using httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, vb.net

I request the entire scraping process plan using `httpwebrequest`, I would like to clear this thing from my previous scraping experience... I used to scrape information from websites using `webbrowsercontrol` in vb.net and I used to follow below plan using `webbrowsercontrol`.

1. Navigating URL in `webbrowsercontrol1`(home page will have button to agree terms and conditions will be clicked using `form1.webbrowser1.document.getelementbyid("").invokemember("clcik")` will navigate to next page.
2. Obviously `webdocumentcomplete` event is key routine which will be fired and decides which routine to call using WB documenttext.
3. The selected routine will puts necessary information using `form1.webbrowser1.document.getelementbyid("").innertext=parm1` and clicks button it goes to step2.
   From there it reaches a search list of records hence  each record will be clicked and information fetched.
4. When final record is completed  page moves `back(goback())` and new details provided.
5. And it goes on.

Currently my client expecting me to do same job using C# ,I successfully finished using the same webbrowsercontrol object...now I need to do the same using httpwebrequest so they can run it through a proxy.

I am requesting some help using `httprequest`... I had knowledge to get the home page response in string format using below piece of code.

```
// Cookie for our session
// Prepare our login HttpWebRequest
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.website.com");

request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

// Retrieve HttpWebResponse
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

// Link the response cookie to the domain
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri("www.website.com"), response.Cookies);

// Prepare our navigate HttpWebRequest, and set his cookie.
HttpWebRequest requestProfile = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.website.com");
requestProfile.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

// Retrieve HttpWebResponse
HttpWebResponse responseProfile = (HttpWebResponse)requestProfile.GetResponse();

// Retrieve stream response and read it to end
Stream st = responseProfile.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(st);
string buffer = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Earlier from buffer I fetch the ID of the home page button form HTML text and  clicks using below piece of code
 `form1.wb1.document.getelementbyid("ID").invokemember("click")`
will navigates to  next page in the browser...now help me clicking on this button and putting details in nextpage using `HTTPWEBREQUEST` ...do we have any events for `httpwebresponse` ? or any other way...

Comment: Web scraping is mostly considered illegal, and there are a lot of lawsuits that ruled the scraping as a felony violation, so I don't really think it's an appropriate topic for SO.

Comment: Question about web scraping, which is illegal

Answer (score 0):

While wholesale copying of website content might be plagerism, in the United States, the courts ruled in Feist Publications v. Rural Telephone Service that duplication of facts is allowable.

What I did was just get the html with a `WebClient` and use Html Tidy to convert that into xml. Then, pulling the elements out of the xml was relatively easy.

Where you run into difficulty is with automating login forms, ajax and the like.